# htaccess redirect pretty URLs to ugly ones

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

So, I'm trying to make my URL's a bit more pretty and sharable. I have a website with some items that users can currently access with `example.com/?i=itemName`. However, I'd like users to be able to write `example.com/itemName` instead.

This means I'd have to do some redirection with htaccess. I want to redirect all URL's to `example.com` itself, but keep the URL the same. To clarify, an example:

User types `example.com/niceItem`. The server shows the content of `example.com`, but keeps the URL as `example.com/niceItem` (alternatively, it can change the URL to `example.com/?i=niceItem`, then I can simply read the URL with javascript and change it back to `example.com/niceItem` in the adress bar).

So far, this is the best I could do:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\/]+)$ /index.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

The idea is to capture the requests that don't have slashes after the first one (like `example.com/niceItem`), and then read the file at `example.com/index.php?i=niceItem`. The problem is, when I load a page like `example.com/niceItem`, the page displays what the value of `i` is with php; it should be `niceItem`, as the link is supposed to be `example.com/?i=niceItem`, but the value of `i` is actually the string `index.php`. Not quite what I wanted. Also, I'd expect the following to work

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\/]+)$ /?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

but this actually causes an internal server error.

So, the question is, why do those not work, and how would I be able to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

---

PS. Actually, this website I'm talking about is a subdomain of `example.com`. So, I have `sub.example.com` which maps to `example.com/sub/`, and I need the URL's to be prettyfied like `sub.example.com/itemName` or `example.com/sub/itemName`. As I mentioned, the format of the URL isn't that big of a deal as long as the `itemName` part is in there. I'll be able to read the URL with javascript and change it to whatever I want once the page has loaded.

Comment: SIdenote, if anyone knows some proper terminology for my question, feel free to suggest a different title. I'm aware the current one isn't too descriptive, but I'm not sure how to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#rewrite-query)

If **i** is the only query argument that will be passed then

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(\?i=)(.*)$"
RewriteRule "(.*)/?$" "$1/%2"
```

If you need to extract **i** only but keep other query args

```
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(.*(?:^|&))i=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
RewriteRule "(.*)/?$" "$1/%2?%1%3"
```

Most every framework provides this sort functionality. It is best not to reinvent the wheel when possible. This is a fragile setup, and it will probably cause you headaches in the future.

Comment: Well, it's just a small site and I'm more of a hobbyist, so the complexity isn't a problem. Also, reinventing the wheel may not be the best thing to do if you just want a wheel, but it's worth it if you want to learn about wheels :)